# How to isolate the spark session for each user on jupyterhub?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have an AD plugin connected to my JupyterHub installation so that users will be authenticated on JupyterHub via AD connector.

The issue is if different users submit their Spark job through Jupyter Notebook on JupyterHub to the shared underlying Spark engine, is there a way that each user will have their isolated Spark session instead of the shared one?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please take your time to familiarize yourself with the site by taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), going through [this brilliant question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, your question lacks your attempt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this deployment mode:

- Users will connect to the shared **JupyterHub** binded to the AD
- If they are authenticated a new **Jupyter Notebook** (server) will be spawned
- Then in their Jupyter Notebook, they will use **Spark** either in local or in cluster mode according to your deployment. In both case, **the driver is dedicated to their usage** (not shared).

In this typical deployment nothing is shared except the Spark Cluster (if any). Each user will be able to get and manage a new `SparkSession`.

See this diagram from [jupyterhub-deploy-docker](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker).

[image]

Comment: hi Romain, really appreciated for your kindly help here! That is really helpful! By the way, i have a very similar case on AWS EMR, if you have time, could you help a check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915066/about-livy-session-for-jupyterhub-on-aws-emr-spark